# Android Studio Flamingo no longer creates debug symbols in App bundles

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, debug-symbols

**Issue description:**
I’m facing the issue that after some upgrades (Android Studio, Gradle plugin, etc) the creation of debug symbols in App bundles no longer happens. My current setup is:

- Android Flamingo 2022.2.1
- Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0
- Gradle Version 8.1.1
- Build tools 33.0.2
- NDK 25.1.8937393
- CMake 3.22.1
- Kotlin 1.8.21
- Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (with all latest updates)

**Reproducing steps:**

- Create a new project and select “Phone and Tablet” -> “Basic Views Activity” from the Templates
- Call the project “Demo Application” and set the Minimum SDK to API 28, leave all other settings at their default
- Use the build.gradle of the project as stated below:

```
     plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21' apply false
    }
```

- Use the build.gradle of the app as stated below:

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
    
    android {
        namespace 'com.example.demoapplication'
        compileSdk 33
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.demoapplication"
            minSdk 28
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                ndk {
                    debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
                }
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '17'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }
        ndkVersion '25.1.8937393'
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    }
```

Notice that minifyEnabled is set to true, ndkVersion 25.1.8937393 is added and that debugSymbolLevel is stated as “FULL”
When Build bundle is selected the app builds fine
When analyzing the App bundle the are no debug symbols in the app-release.aab file (see screenshot below):
image.png

With my ‘normal’ App, the same thing happens. I must note that in the past debug symbols were created, at some point of upgrading to a newer version (AGP amongst others) it stopped creating them (and I don't know what caused it).

**What I’ve tried**

- Tried several different Android Gradle Plugin versions
- Tried various NDK versions (higher and lower)
- Tried different CMake versions
- Added ndkPath to my build.gradle
- Tried removing the ndkVersion from build.gradle file

I don’t know what I’m missing here. I also can’t find any logfile that could give me a clue why it’s not working.

This github repository contains the demo application demonstrating that debug symbols are not created (at least on my system):
https://github.com/Chris-NL/Demo_Application

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I see this in your gradle file - ndkVersion '25.1.8937393' - In your SDK Tools/NDK, do you select the same version?

Comment: I have matched these versions.

Comment: Please also review: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280958690

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue, is being tracked here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279489616

A fix will be included in Flamingo Patch 2.

Comment: Reading the issue on the link you supplied, that seems to be another type of issue: "After updating to Flamingo, the native debugger doesn't load symbols of my native library."

Using Flamingo patch 2, my issue is still there. Let me know how you might have solved my issue with the demo application I've provided.